# How to check if cite-command is empty?

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, undefined

I would like to add automatically the information about the translator of a(n ancient) book, if there is no translator, it should be me as translator.

> How can I check whether the `bibtex-entry` has defined a translator or not?

My approach fails:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents,etoolbox}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Varro_ling,
  author      = {Terentius Varro, Marcus},
  editor      = {William Heinemann},
  title       = {On the Latin Language},
  location    = {Cambridge and London},
  year        = {1993},
  volume      = {I--II},
  series      = {Loeb Classical Library},
  number      = {333--334},
  edition     = {3},
  origtitle   = {de lingua latina},
  translator  = {Kent, Roland G.},
  shorthand   = {Varro ling.},
  shortauthor = {Varro},
  keywords    = {ancient},
  options     = {ancient},
  origdate    = {1938},
}
@Book{Varro_rust,
  author      = {Terentius Varro, Marcus},
  origtitle   = {de re rustica},
  shorthand   = {Varro rust.},
  shortauthor = {Varro},
  keywords    = {ancient},
  options     = {ancient},
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[           
  backend=biber,
style=archaeologie,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\makeatletter

\newcommand\mytrans[1]{Transl.
\def\thetranslator{\citetranslator{#1}}
\ifundef{\thetranslator}{by me}{\citetranslator{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Transl. (Varro ling): \citetranslator{Varro_ling}\par
Transl. (Varro rust): \citetranslator{Varro_rust}\par
\mytrans{Varro_ling}\par
\mytrans{Varro_rust}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @moewe you are right, but that would involve more work since I think the users would like to define the `me` individually. But it is an approach!

Comment: Have a look at my answer. It is absolutely no problem at all to say `\printtext{\me}` instead of `\printtext{me}` and define `\me` later (or earlier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\ifnameundef` from 'within' `biblatex` (only in a `bibmacro` or `\DeclareCiteCommand`).

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mytrans}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifnameundef{translator}
     {\printtext{me}}
     {\printnames{translator}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```